# Execute gphoto2 on lighty/lighttpd on raspbian

Tags: php, raspbian, libgphoto2, lighty

I try to execute this command with the PHP command [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

```
exec ("gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download --filename ".$path, $output, $returnVal);
```

I use a valid filename and when I execute the command with the parameters of the variables in bash, it works. However, with php it doesn't. I don't get a reply of the exec command.
I'm using raspbian with lighty and the php5 module. That works with other samples fine.
I tryed [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) without success, too.

Can someone help me?

Comment: *"I don't get a reply of the exec command"* - What exactely does `exec()` return? Is `gphoto2` in the path for the corresponding user?

Comment: It's like the command is missing. There is nothing happen. When I use `command -v gphoto2` for locating gphoto2. I get this path: `/usr/local/bin/gphoto2`

Comment: Sometime, I get the exit code 127

Comment: And have you looked up what *127* means? What happens when you take the full path?

Comment: I tryed it with this command `/usr/local/bin/gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download --filename photo_`. Sometimes I get the return code 127 which means _"command not found"_ or code 1 which means _"Catchall for general errors"_. If I use the same command on bash, it works fine.
That's the source: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

Comment: Get the path and check if `/usr/local/bin` is in there. `var_dump(exec('which gphoto2'))` - `var_dump(exec('echo $PATH'))`.

Comment: The replys of teh var_dumps: `var_dump(exec('which gphoto2'))`: `string(0) ""`   `var_dump(exec('echo $PATH'))`: `string(29) "/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"` Is that what you need?

Comment: As m02ph3u5 suggested, it does not look like gphoto2 is in the PATH when the PHP is run.  Use `exec("/usr/local/bin/gphoto2 ...)` or add /usr/local/bin to the PATH in the PHP environment for the script.